# Deleting a key from Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to delete a key from a dictionary but my code doesn't delete anything. Also it seems just ignoring the if statement.

Thanks for the help guys

Here is my code:

```
empVar={}
empVar[25]="square of 5"
empVar.update({3:9})
print(empVar)
print(empVar.keys())
print(empVar.values())

keyValToDel=input("Enter key to del: ")
if keyValToDel in empVar:
    empVar.pop(keyValToDel)
    print("deleted Var: " + keyValToDel)
print(empVar)
```

Comment: As python is strongly typed, `25` is not the same as `"25"`. Convert user input into a number using `keyValToDel = int(keyValToDel)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the input from str to int because "3" is not 3.

```
empVar={}
empVar[25]="square of 5"
empVar.update({3:9})
print(empVar)
print(empVar.keys())
print(empVar.values())

keyValToDel=input("Enter key to del: ")
if int(keyValToDel) in empVar:
    empVar.pop(int(keyValToDel))
    print("deleted Var: " + keyValToDel)
print(empVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns a string. Your dictionary's key is an integer, so you need to cast the input's result into an `int` before deleting the key:

```
keyValToDel=int(input("Enter key to del: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is because an int can't be equal to a string in Python. You need to type case your inputs, to validate them.

```
empVar={}
empVar[25]="square of 5"
empVar.update({9:'square of 3'})

keyValToDel=int(input("Enter key to del: "))
del(empVar[keyValToDel])
print(empVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. Its my first time learning coding so what can I search to understand more about why is this the case? btw I edited my code to this and it works :)

```
empVar={}
empVar[25]="square of 5"
empVar.update({3:9})
print(empVar)
print(empVar.keys())
print(empVar.values())

keyValToDel=input("Enter key to del: ")
keyValToDel = int(keyValToDel)
if int(keyValToDel) in empVar:
   empVar.pop(keyValToDel)
   print("deleted " + str(keyValToDel))
print(empVar)enter code here
```

Comment: You just have to remember that a variable has a type. `42` is integer number 42, while `"42"` is a string of 2 characters, character `'4'` followed by character `'2'`. That's not the same thing.

Comment: Compare: `"2" + "3" == "23"` but `2 + 3 == 5`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. In python 2.7 you to do this tweak as you need to convert into to str for printing with + sign.

```
empVar={} 
empVar[25]="square of 5" 
empVar.update({3:9}) 
print(empVar) 
print(empVar.keys()) 
print(empVar.values()) 
keyValToDel=input("Enter key to del: ")
if keyValToDel in empVar: 
    empVar.pop(keyValToDel) 
    print("deleted Var: " + str(keyValToDel)) 
    print(empVar)
```

Hope your problem is solved.